# Meteor - Android white screen

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I have this Meteor app and I want to publish on Google Play but once the app is installed and I open it I get the white screen after the splash page. When I test  my app locally with `meteor run android-device --mobile-server=...` the app loads fine.

It would be hard to post my code since there is a lot of code but what can I do to identify the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: We are having the same issue but with iOS. Have you found a solution? Have you tried adding the whitelist plugin? Did that help?

Comment: I was using `https` for the `--mobile-server` parameter but the SSL certificate wasn't properly set.